# Making changes to functions of protoc generated APIs

Tags: function, constructor, reference, protocol-buffers, customization

Suppose I have a `person.proto` file-

```
syntax = "proto3";

/* Class Person */
message  Person{ 
    string  name = 2;
}
```

Then, I use protoc to generate the source code in Python, or C++.

**Question 1:**
Suppose I generated the API code, now what I can do to create an object of Person class, is:

```
person = person_pb2.Person()  #  In Python
Person person;                // In C++
```

What I want is, every time I create an object of `Person` class, the reference to this object is stored with a unique ID inside a map.

Basically, I want to create something like a map, to store the reference of every object of each class that is ever created.

One way to achieve this I thought of is to add a custom line of code (which calls a different function) to the classes' **constructor**, such that every time an object is created, that function will add reference to it to the map.

Is this approach good? If yes, then how to achieve this- customizing class constructors of protoc generated source code (in every language- C++, Python, Java, etc.). If no, then what could be a better solution?

---

**Question 2:** For the fields, we have **setters** and getters. e.g.

```
person.name = ...     #  In Python
person.set_name(...)  // In CPP
```

So, what if I want to add something more to the `set_name()` function, how can we do that?
Like if I want to call a function inside `set_name()`, then how to achieve that?

---

In short, both the questions sum up as "**How to make changes to the functions of API that protoc generates (in all the languages)?**"

Is there something to do with plugins? Or with descriptor files? Or something else?

Comment: Why not just create a custom subclass, inheriting from the generated object?

Comment: But there is no concept of Inheritance in protobufs, right?

Comment: There is no inheritance that can be defined in `.proto` files. But AFAIK the generated classes are just normal Python/C++ classes which you can inherit in the type specific to each language. But apparently it is not recommended after all: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242760/inheriting-from-generated-protocol-buffer-classes

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. It is not recommended as well as for every language we will have to write something generic, so hectic too.